# $n$-ary relations vs subsets and binary relations

Tags: logic, set-theory

A relation between sets is a subset of the Cartesian product of those sets.

A subset of any set is a binary relation between the subset(correction: superset) and the set $X = \{True, False\}$, that maps to $True$, i.e. a subset is a subset of the Cartesian product of the subset(correction: superset) and the set $X$.

Hence, is the subset relation, or binary relations in general, required to define all $n$-ary relations? Is the notion of binary relations more fundamental than even that of unary and $0$-ary relations?

Edit: Can you define binary relations with unary relations? I can't imagine that you could without again appealing back to binary relations?

Comment: I suggest not flinging around the word "is" in quite so spectacular a manner. Even in informal mathematical discourse I would object when I heard someone say *.. a subset [of $X$]* ***is*** *a subset of the Cartesian product of the subset and the set $X$*.

Comment: Note too that your particular binary relation happens to be a **function** from the whole set (not just the subset) to your set $X$.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Ah, yes. It's the whole set, not the subset. But isn't a function just a type of relation?

Comment: Yes it is. A relation containing exactly one ordered pair $(s, t)$ for each $s$ in its domain.

Comment: The binary relation $\in$ is more fundamental than the subset relation and the notion of cartesian product.

Comment: You define ‘subset’ using the term ‘subset’ … that doesn’t work. ‘Subset’ is usually defined in terms of membership… and membership is taken as fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, its important to not confuse being-equal-to ("is"), and being-isomorphic-to (i.e. having the same cardinality).

With this language, you are observing that for any set $X$, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X \times 2)$, I'm writing $2=\{True, False\}$ here. In fact, you can check that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is isomorphic to $2^X$, that is, the functions from $X$ to $2$.

Note finally that any $n$-ary relation is isomorphic to a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X \times N)$, with $N$ being any set of $n$ elements. In particular, that means that for $n \geq 2$, we would have
$$\mathcal{P}(X) \cong 2^X \leq \mathcal{P}(X \times 2) \leq \mathcal{P}(X \times n)$$
Where $\cong$ means isomorphism, and $A \leq B$ means that $A$ is isomorphic to a subset of $B$.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure how the difference relates to the questions in the last paragraph though. Would $2^X$ be the cardinality of the powerset of set $X$? If so, in what way is it isomorphic to the *subsets* of the other sets?

Comment: "$\mathcal{P}(X)$ is isomorphic to a subset of $X \times 2$". How could that be when that Cartesian product has smaller cardinality than the power set?

Comment: @JohnColeman You're absolutely right, my bad. I fixed it now I believe.

Answer (score 0):

No, $n$-ary relations can be defined without explicit or implicit reliance on the binary relations. For example, a ternary relation $T$ on a set $S$ is any subset of $S^3$.

You could, if you wished, then define a function $\tau:S^3\rightarrow\{{\bf TRUE}, {\bf FALSE}\}$ that answers the question “Is $(s_1, s_2, s_3) \in S^3$ in $T$?”

Comment: Thanks, but isn't being a subset a binary relation between its superset and ${True, False}?

Comment: *Is-a-subset-of* is a binary relation in $X \times Y$, where the elements of $X$ and $Y$ are themselves sets. Oh, I suppose one could define it where some or even all of the elements of $X$ and $Y$ are other than sets, but every element of the relation has the form $(x, y)$, where both $x$ and $y$ **are** sets.